# How to print a date field value on a page?

Tags: entities, datetime

In Drupal 7, I have created a node type x,  with a date field D:M:Y. Here is an edited Devel tree array structure message for easy reading.

content >> system_main >> nodes >> 31 >> field_Mydate >> #items >> 0 >> value

How do I render the particular node date field value from the above extract?

Answer (score 3):

You should use Drupal's ['format_date'](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7) function.

Example:
format_date(strtotime($entity->field_mydate['und'][0]['value2']) ,'custom','F j, Y');

Comment: I tried printing using the code you suggested but i'm not sure what ['value2'] refers to, or how to fit node id into context. I understand the format_date syntax, but not the middle section. I assumed more details displayed in Devel, would be be used in the code

Comment: Value2 is the end date. (Date fields has 2 values in its array). Try using dpm or any other debug method to see the exact structure of the field (from the $content array). By the way, are you adding the above code to your page template?

Comment: thanks, yes this worked with the dpm/devel and I inputed that info into the code. I also realized it only worked if put into node.tpl. cheers. I'll post my results once I am able to post into answers section.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?php
print format_date(strtotime($content['field_Mydate']['#items'][0]['value']), 'custom', 'F j, Y'); ?>
```

I used the format_date function as suggested.
I entered the values based on Devel info, and inserted into node.tpl.